# Agrupar JSON por año JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Teniendo la siguiente respuesta JSON desde una API, que seria la siguiente:

```
    {
        "n_cont_menor": 1, 
        "year": "2012", 
        "total_imp_menor": 3600.0
    }, 
    {
        "n_cont_menor": 78, 
        "year": "2014", 
        "total_imp_menor": 760613.82
    }, 
    {
        "n_cont_menor": 84, 
        "year": "2015", 
        "total_imp_menor": 920440.32
    }, 
    {
        "n_cont_menor": 49, 
        "year": "2016", 
        "total_imp_menor": 381570.92
    },
    {
        "n_abierto": 1, 
        "year": "2005", 
        "total_imp_abierto": 18071.45
    }, 
    {
        "n_abierto": 2, 
        "year": "2012", 
        "total_imp_abierto": 683366.72
    }, 
    {
        "n_abierto": 2, 
        "year": "2013", 
        "total_imp_abierto": 610771.92
    },
```

El resultado que se desea obtener, es un JSON con los datos agrupador por años (ya que algunos se repiten) de la siguiente manera:

```
    {
        "year": "2012", 
        "n_cont_menor": 1,
        "total_imp_menor": 3600.0
        "n_abierto": 2,
        "total_imp_abierto": 683366.72
    }, 
    {
        "year": "2013", 
        "n_cont_menor": 0,
        "total_imp_menor": 0,
        "n_abierto": 2,
        "total_imp_abierto": 610771.92
    },
    {
        "year": "2014", 
        "n_cont_menor": 78,
        "total_imp_menor": 760613.82,
        "n_abierto": 0,
        "total_imp_abierto": 0
    },
```

Y asi con todo el JSON, agrupar todos las clave/valor por el año (si en un año no hay datos de una clave, se pone 0). He intentado de varias formas y no hay manera...

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?. Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Dices que has intentado varias formas, sube al menos una de ellas para ver que lo has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Hay que aclarar algo, en un objeto de javascript no puede haber propiedades repetidas, si al momento de parsear el JSON (lo cual no requieres hacer), se encuentran propiedades repetidas se dejara la ultima informacion recolectada en esa propiedad y las demas propiedades coincidentes serán descartadas, por lo tanto lo que planteas es simplemente imposible de manera directa, ahora, de manera indirecta una posible solución es solo tener propiedades unicas para respetar la estructura de los JSON, pero que estas propiedades almacenen en un array los valores de las propiedades que se repiten.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya lo solucioné, puse una respuesta con la solución

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he logrado de la siguiente manera:

```
api_merged = Object.values(response.result.reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b.year] = Object.assign(a[b.year] || {}, b);
    return a;
}, {}));
```